# Macro in macro loop

Tags: vba, loops

I'm trying to run a macro that loops certain other macros but it's not working.

Each of the individual macros do exactly what they are supposed to, I have tested them, but when trying to run the code below, the first macro outside the loop works and then nothing else happens.

I've tried various different loop methods (the latest is below), including methods posted on this website already.

```
Sub MasterMacro()

Dim EndCriterion As Long
Dim i As Long

Cells.Find(What:="Step", After:=Cells(1, 1), LookAt:=xlPart).Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
EndCriterion = ActiveCell.Row

Application.Run "CColumnFind"

For i = 1 To EndCriterion

    Application.Run "Stepper"
    Application.Run "RetrieveIdeal"
    Application.Run "RecompileArray"
    Application.Run "Return"

Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

End Sub
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best guess, but it's hard to tell what's going on in your other macros...

```
Sub MasterMacro()

Dim EndCriterion As Long
Dim i As Long, f As Range

Set f = Cells.Find(What:="Step", After:=Cells(1, 1), LookAt:=xlPart)
If Not f Is Nothing Then
    EndCriterion = f.End(xlDown).Row
Else
    MsgBox "'Step' not found!"
    Exit Sub
End If

CColumnFind

For i = 1 To EndCriterion
        Stepper
    RetrieveIdeal
    RecompileArray
    Return

Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

End Sub
```